# Obtain a data.frame from a mixed type list

Tags: r

I have a list (well, a little longer):

```
lst <- list(c(x=1, y=2), NULL)
```

How would I obtain a data.frame like this from my list?

```
data.frame(x=c(1, NaN), y=c(2,NaN))
    x   y
1   1   2
2 NaN NaN
```

Probably there's a clever function instead of iterating with a loop and appending (that would be memory-inefficient).

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x))`

Comment: Great! What is the idea behind `do.call` here? Couldn't you call it directly?

Comment: It is a list, so you need `do.call`

Comment: Would you mind answering the question so I can check it? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` to replace the NULL elements with `NaN` and then `rbind` with `do.call`

```
 do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x))
```

Or we changed the `NULL` elements to `NaN` based on the logical index (`sapply(lst, is.null)`) and use `rbind`.

```
 lst[sapply(lst, is.null)] <- NaN
  setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst), paste0('V', 1:2))
```